# Automator to rename files with prompt

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I was wondering how to create an automator shell script to rename files, while prompting with window (or terminal) to enter the new name. I have spend months trying to do this using bash script in automator, unsuccessfully.

```shell
for f in *.md
do
    mv "$f" "test - $f"
done
```

This is basically the idea in script form. What I need is the "test" to be a prompted dialog where I enter what I want.

Comment: Hi Emmanual. Is the code you posted above the literal code you have been trying to get to work, or is it missing the percent signs due to a copy-paste anomaly?

Comment: Get it working in AppleScript first (which has adequate user I/O for this kind of stuff), and then embed the script in a workflow.

Comment: Percent signs? Hi, I don't know programming, so the code may be wrong. I would like to implement it in automator, so "test" would be a prompted dialog window to write anything to be used to rename the files.